# Will using a Timeline with a duration of 1 millisecond with an indefinite cycle count provide an accurate time for a stopwatch?

Tags: java, performance, javafx, timeline

I've created a simple stopwatch using a Timeline, but I'm wondering if it will be accurate. Here is the code:

```
LongProperty timeMillis = new SimpleLongProperty(0);
timer = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1), e -> timeMillis.set(timeMillis.get()+1));
timer.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
timer.start();
```

My question is, will there be some kind of delay between each millisecond while it increments timeMillis? Or some kind of delay caused by counting 1 millisecond at a time?

Comment: Why would you not use `System.nanoTime()` or similar to measure elapsed time?

Comment: @JonSkeet How would I create a binding around System.nanoTime() to ensure that timeMillis is always correct (to the millisecond)? I'm trying to put a stopwatch in my UI, so I need to bind some text property to timeMillis.

Comment: You would remember the value when you started the stopwatch, then frequently (e.g. every 10ms, up to you) call `System.nanoTime()` again, take the difference between "now" and "the start", divide by 1000,000 and you're there...

Comment: Probably a better implementation - in a JavaFX context - of @JonSkeet's idea is to use an `AnimationTimer`. The `handle(...)` method of an `AnimationTimer` is called once per rendered frame, with a nanosecond-level timestamp based on `System.nanoTime()` for that frame. This would give the same degree of accuracy but would avoid the overhead of an excessive number of frames that would never be presented to the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your timeline approach will be reasonably accurate, but will compute the time far more frequently than the UI will be able to render it. JavaFX, by default, throttles frame rendering at 60 frames per second, so only about 6% of the calls to `timemillis.set(...)` will ever be represented in the UI.

A more efficient approach, that performs computation when the UI is rendered, but no more frequently, is to use an `AnimationTimer`. The `AnimationTimer` has a `handle()` method that is guaranteed to be executed exactly once per rendering pulse:

```
LongProperty timeMillis = new SimpleLongProperty(0);

AnimationTimer stopwatch = new AnimationTimer() {

    private static final long STOPPED = -1 ;
    private long startTime = STOPPED ;

    @Override
    public void handle(long timestamp) {
        if (startTime == STOPPED) {
            startTime = timestamp ;
        }
        long elapsedNanos = timestamp - startTime ;
        long elapsedMillis = elapsedNanos / 1_000_000 ;
        timeMillis.set(elapsedMillis);
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        startTime = STOPPED ;
        super.stop();
    }
};
```

Now simply call `stopwatch.start()` and `stopwatch.stop()` to start and stop the timer. You can add some `pause()` functionality too, which requires a little more work...

Answer (score 2):

Using Jon Skeet's suggestion, I timed it myself, and it seems to be pretty accurate.

```
LongProperty timelineMillis = new SimpleLongProperty(0);
Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1), e -> timelineMillis.set(timelineMillis.get()+1)));
timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);

Long startNano = System.nanoTime();
timeline.play();

Timeline checkTime = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1000), e -> {
    Long currentTimelineTime = timelineMillis.get();
    Long currentNanoTime = (System.nanoTime() - startNano) / 1000000;
    System.out.println("Timeline time: " + currentTimelineTime + ", Nano time: " + currentNanoTime + ", Difference: " + (currentTimelineTime - currentNanoTime));
}));
checkTime.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
checkTime.play();
```

Output of the first 30 seconds:

```
Timeline time: 1010, Nano time: 1012, Difference: -2
Timeline time: 2002, Nano time: 2004, Difference: -2
Timeline time: 3010, Nano time: 3012, Difference: -2
Timeline time: 4002, Nano time: 4004, Difference: -2
Timeline time: 5010, Nano time: 5012, Difference: -2
Timeline time: 6002, Nano time: 6004, Difference: -2
Timeline time: 7010, Nano time: 7012, Difference: -2
Timeline time: 8002, Nano time: 8004, Difference: -2
Timeline time: 9010, Nano time: 9012, Difference: -2
Timeline time: 10002, Nano time: 10004, Difference: -2
Timeline time: 11010, Nano time: 11012, Difference: -2
Timeline time: 12002, Nano time: 12004, Difference: -2
Timeline time: 13010, Nano time: 13012, Difference: -2
Timeline time: 14003, Nano time: 14004, Difference: -1
Timeline time: 15011, Nano time: 15012, Difference: -1
Timeline time: 16003, Nano time: 16004, Difference: -1
Timeline time: 17011, Nano time: 17012, Difference: -1
Timeline time: 18002, Nano time: 18003, Difference: -1
Timeline time: 19010, Nano time: 19011, Difference: -1
Timeline time: 20002, Nano time: 20004, Difference: -2
Timeline time: 21010, Nano time: 21012, Difference: -2
Timeline time: 22002, Nano time: 22004, Difference: -2
Timeline time: 23010, Nano time: 23012, Difference: -2
Timeline time: 24002, Nano time: 24004, Difference: -2
Timeline time: 25010, Nano time: 25012, Difference: -2
Timeline time: 26002, Nano time: 26004, Difference: -2
Timeline time: 27010, Nano time: 27012, Difference: -2
Timeline time: 28002, Nano time: 28004, Difference: -2
Timeline time: 29010, Nano time: 29012, Difference: -2
Timeline time: 30002, Nano time: 30004, Difference: -2
```

Comment: I believe the internal handling of a timeline works on the same basic principal: it remembers when the timeline was started, which was the last keyframe invoked, and on iteration of the event loop checks the current time against the start time to see if more keyframes should be invoked. So the discrepancies will not accumulate and will stay approximately constant.